# When did Ben Franklin sleep with Doctor Strange's girlfriend?

Tags: marvel, deadpool, doctor-strange

In *Deadpool* (2012) #3, the titular Merc with a Mouth is fighting resurrected US presidents and is assisted by the ghostly visage of Ben Franklin. When he asks Doctor Strange to help, this happens:

[image: Strange: "And Mr. Franklin…I've not forgotten or forgiven you for sleeping with my girlfriend." Editors Note: "Ben slept with Clea back in the '70s. Look it up."]

Did Ben Franklin really sleep with Doctor Strange's girlfriend, Clea? And if so, when did that happen?

Comment: http://www.therobotspajamas.com/once-dr-stranges-wife-cheated-on-him-with-ben-franklin/

Comment: When Chris Hastings entered the scene.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Doctor Strange (v2) #018](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_Vol_2_18) from 1976. After a brief sojourn through time, Strange and Clea encounter Ben Franklin. Strange proceeds ahead and leaves Clea and Franklin in each other's company. The randy old goat then proceeds to seduce Clea.

[image]

Later…

[image]

It may interest you to know that in a subsequent issue it was revealed that 'Franklin' was in fact [Stygyro](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Stygyro_(Earth-616)) in disguise, a fact that Strange seems to have forgotten by 2016.

[image]

<sub><sup>Information originally found on http://www.therobotspajamas.com/once-dr-stranges-wife-cheated-on-him-with-ben-franklin/</sup></sub>

Comment: @Thunderforge - Yeah, the retcon was *de-retconned* it seems.

Comment: Actually, in reading the issues (thanks to Marvel Unlimited), Strange is fighting Stygyro in Atlantis while Franklin is seducing Clea. The next issue happens some time later, and Strange finds Clea with Ben Franklin, who turns out to be Stygyro. The real Franklin shows up by the end. While saying goodbye to her, he says he wishes he would have had a chance to spend some time with Clea. It's not clear how long he was Stygyro. Putting on an act for Strange to hide the fact that he slept with her, or a clumsy retcon of the previous issue? You make the call!

Comment: @Thunderforge - I'm gonna leave it as it is. The comments will point anyone who's interested in digging deeper toward the appropriate resources.